# Empirical Line Method (ELM) in ArcGIS Pro (2)

Tags: arcgis-pro, imagery

I am working with Remotely-sensed imagery (10x10cm) from the Netherlands.

My images from 2017, 2018, 2019 and 2020 from the same area, recorded in the same time of the year, all look different regarding colour brightness, likely caused by atmospheric circumstances. As I would like to compare my images, I would like the images to be, well... comparable. For that purpose I would like to apply the empirical line method, using one image as reference image and standardise the other images to that reference image. I would like to apply this method to each band, rather than to the image as a whole.

In literature, I often see authors using this empirical line method, but I do not understand HOW they actually use it in software. I have access to ArcGIS Pro (incl all extensions, e.g. image analyst) to solve this problem.

So: can someone tell me how to actually apply the empirical line method to an image and reference image, in the ArcGIS software?